# CorePlot Label Touch Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm hoping to capture the touch event of an axis label in CorePlot. I'm aware of the existing of the `plot:dataLabelWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` method, which is similar, but not exactly what I'm hoping for (I want the label, not the data label). I'm also aware of the `plotSpace:shouldHandlePointingDeviceXXEvent`. This seems currently to be the only solution -- taking that point, translating it to the plot, and then trying to find the corresponding bar. Obviously this isn't really ideal, am I missing something in the documentation for an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added axis delegate methods to make this easy. See the `CPTAxisDelegate` [documentation](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_axis_delegate-p.html) for details.

Comment: Awesome! This is _exactly_ what I needed. When is this version due to be released, any idea?

Comment: Read through your change, you ended up doing it the way I was trying to avoid :/ Too much yucky point conversion math, though I don't think there is much of any other option. Thanks for implementing this, and with regard to my last comment, is there a mailing list specifically for releases?

Comment: Releases will be announced on the [Core Plot discussion board](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coreplot-discuss) or you can watch the [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/list).

Comment: I'm planning to do another release after Xcode 5 is released to the public and we clean up any issues that arise.